# Web-based alternative to a desktop application

Tags: architecture, web, project

I need to write an application that must be able to communicate with different devices connected via COM-ports (such as fiscal registrar, bank note validator, thermal printer and etc.) and display various data on dual monitor. I am good at WPF programming and could implement a desktop application using this technology, but I would like to come as close as possible to a web-based implementation, as many other things are more comfortable to be done with web.

I understand that web-browser cannot access COM-ports directly, but maybe someone could offer an architecture of a web-application which could replace desktop application in my case.

Comment: I couldn't find much good information, but good luck. I'd like to hear what you come up with eventually. [This discussion](http://java.dzone.com/why-desktop-not-webapp) went mostly the other way about why you may *not* want to move to the web.

Answer (score 0):

In case you haven't found what I did in a quick search, [here](http://www.walking-productions.com/jsserial/new/JSSerial.html) is an explanation about using a signed java applet to communicate with com ports. I assume that would be very non-trivial to extend that to all the interfaces you discussed.